# When dotnet tool won't start up (failed to initialize) what environment variable do I set to get more verbose information?

Tags: linux, asp.net-core, .net-core

I know I've read on a blog somewhere or other that you can set some environment variable to give you more information when you have a crash at startup invoking the `dotnet` tool (asp.net core dotnet command line tool).

I'm using `dotnet` 1.0.0 rtm on an OpenSuSE linux system and it's crashing like this:

```
> dotnet version
Failed to initialize CoreCLR, HRESULT: 0x80131500
```

To get more information about why, is there some environment variable I can set to tell me why it won't start up?

I do know you can get some unix system info with `dotnet --info` but that also crashes in my case with the same failed to initialize error.

I know I can do an strace (strace dotnet version) but I think there's something BUILT IN

Comment: Created github issue to track what is I suspect an unreasonable set of binary library dependencies in the dotnet core binaries.

https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/207

Comment: You seem to be missing some dependencies. From the top of my head - you need to check libicu, libunwind, libssl libcurl. There's a script the dotnet repo (dotnet-install.sh) that tells you what dependencies you are missing. I tried openSuSe 13.2 and ti worked. The version you are trying is not in the platform graph (https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/pkg/Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms/runtime.json#L356-L368) so not sure if it will work.

Comment: I actually have the correct dependencies (at least in name) but not in version. I am using a newer version of OpenSUSE than is currently supported by the dotnet 1.0.0 binaries for linux.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The environment variable you're looking for is `COREHOST_TRACE=1`.